# How do I make an edge that is parallel to the one that I have selected?

Tags: vertices, edges

I want to make another edge using the vertex I have above the selected one. It will connect the middle part to the outer circle, just like the edge under it.

However, none of the vertices that are on the circle will create a parallel line with the edge I have already created.

How can I make a vertex that is in just the right spot to create a parallel line?

Or, what is the best way to make this parallel edge?

[image: selected edge]

[image]

Comment: You can select that top vertex and G + G to vertex slide and line it up, if that's an acceptable workaround

Comment: @AllenSimpson Well I would like it to end up the same thickness as the center part, and if I do that it'll change the thickness, also if I do that I assume I'll just be eyeballing it rather than having them certainly be parallel